# Is it possible to change the Edit Counter of Users to show the accurate progress on editorial badges?

Tags: feature-request, editing, users

The [Edit Counter of Users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) shows all edits, even the edits that doesn't count on the [Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) or [Copy Editor badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions). It's kind of confusing to see an edit count that doesn't match a goal to reach.

But there are better ways to display edits - such as this query on data: [Copy Editor progress (including tags and about me)](http://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/87243/copy-editor-progress-including-tags-and-about-me), I've just composed out of curiosity.

Is it possible to change the Edit Counter of Users to show the accurate progress on editorial badges?

Answer (score 3):

While your main question is more one for Meta.Stackoverflow I can give you some extra hints for how to track your progress on the Copy Editor badge.

If you go to the Review section and hover over the progress indicator against any of the review items you will see an enhanced tooltip-type affair showing your badge progress:

[image]

I am not sure as I passed the Strunk and White badge before this review option was available but I would *assume* that instead of the Copy Editor progress you'll see the S&W one in it's place until you have been awarded that, which is replaced with Copy Editor progress so you can monitor that.

Comment: No, S&W is not displayed in place of Copy Editor. Even if you have not completed 80 approved edits (required for S&W), the dropdown still shows progress for Copy Editor.

Comment: I'm surprised that more of the achievements that are "do a certain number of things" don't have counters like this.